# Resetting star value on submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a modal with star rating option and textarea on submit i want to reset the values.I'm able to do with text area. but star is not resetting.How can i reset the stars to zero

```js
var ratingValue;
var feedback;

$(document).ready(function () {

  // Get the modal
  modal = document.getElementById("starModal");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  starClose = document.getElementById("starClose");
  feedSubmit = document.getElementById("feedSubmit");
  feedbackContent = document.getElementById("feedbackContent");

  // star modal ends


  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $("#stars li")
    .on("mouseover", function () {
      var onStar = parseInt($(this).data("value"), 10); // The star currently mouse on

      // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .children("li.star")
        .each(function (e) {
          if (e < onStar) {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
          }
        });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .children("li.star")
        .each(function (e) {
          $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });

  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $("#stars li").on("click", function () {
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data("value"), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children("li.star");

    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass("selected");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass("selected");
    }

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    ratingValue = parseInt($("#stars li.selected").last().data("value"), 10);
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue > 1) {
      msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    } else {
      msg =
        "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    // responseMessage(msg);
  });
});


document.getElementById("feedSubmit").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(ratingValue);
  feedback = feedbackContent.value;
  // postRate();
  ratingValue = 0;
  feedbackContent.value = '';
  // modal.style.display = "none";

  console.log("end///");
});
```

```css
/* Rating Star Widgets Style */
.rating-stars ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.rating-stars ul > li.star {
  display:inline-block;
  
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star > i.fa {
  font-size:2.5em; /* Change the size of the stars */
  color:#ccc; /* Color on idle state */
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.hover > i.fa {
  color:#FFCC36;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.selected > i.fa {
  color:#FF912C;
}


.btn-submit{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.feedback {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 75px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}


.rating-stars ul{
  margin-left:10rem
}

.modal-header{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

/* starModal ends */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span>Rate US!!</span>
          <span class="close" id="starClose">&times;</span>

        </div>

        <section class='rating-widget'>
  
          <!-- Rating Stars Box -->
          <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
            <ul id='stars'>
              <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          <div class='success-box'>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            <!-- <img alt='tick image' width='32' src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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'/> -->
            <div class='text-message'></div>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
          </div>
          
      </section>  
      <div id="feedback" style="margin-bottom: 164px;">
        <textarea name="feedback" id="feedbackContent" placeholder="Please Proveide the feedback" class="feedback"></textarea>

      </div>   
      <div class="submit" id="submit">
        <button class="btn-submit" id="feedSubmit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      
      
      </div>
```

How to reset the stars to zero. On submit i want the star highlighting removed(remove the selected stars). How can i handle stars?
Can anyone help.really appreciate.

Comment: why not simply remove class `selected` from star ? i.e :`$("li.star").removeClass("selected");`

Comment: Use this : `$('.star.selected').removeClass('selected');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this, you can do it by removing the selected class in submit function. below is fiddle

```js
var ratingValue;
var feedback;

$(document).ready(function () {

  // Get the modal
  modal = document.getElementById("starModal");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  starClose = document.getElementById("starClose");
  feedSubmit = document.getElementById("feedSubmit");
  feedbackContent = document.getElementById("feedbackContent");

  // star modal ends


  /* 1. Visualizing things on Hover - See next part for action on click */
  $("#stars li")
    .on("mouseover", function () {
      var onStar = parseInt($(this).data("value"), 10); // The star currently mouse on

      // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .children("li.star")
        .each(function (e) {
          if (e < onStar) {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
          }
        });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .children("li.star")
        .each(function (e) {
          $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
    });

  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $("#stars li").on("click", function () {
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data("value"), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children("li.star");

    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass("selected");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass("selected");
    }

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    ratingValue = parseInt($("#stars li.selected").last().data("value"), 10);
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue > 1) {
      msg = "Thanks! You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    } else {
      msg =
        "We will improve ourselves. You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars.";
    }
    // responseMessage(msg);
  });
});


document.getElementById("feedSubmit").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(ratingValue);
  feedback = feedbackContent.value;
  ratingValue = 0;
  feedbackContent.value = '';
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

  console.log("end///");
});
```

```css
/* Rating Star Widgets Style */
.rating-stars ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
.rating-stars ul > li.star {
  display:inline-block;
  
}

/* Idle State of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star > i.fa {
  font-size:2.5em; /* Change the size of the stars */
  color:#ccc; /* Color on idle state */
}

/* Hover state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.hover > i.fa {
  color:#FFCC36;
}

/* Selected state of the stars */
.rating-stars ul > li.star.selected > i.fa {
  color:#FF912C;
}


.btn-submit{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.feedback {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 75px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}


.rating-stars ul{
  margin-left:10rem
}

.modal-header{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

/* starModal ends */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span>Rate US!!</span>
          <span class="close" id="starClose">&times;</span>

        </div>

        <section class='rating-widget'>
  
          <!-- Rating Stars Box -->
          <div class='rating-stars text-center'>
            <ul id='stars'>
              <li class='star' title='Poor' data-value='1'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Fair' data-value='2'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Good' data-value='3'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='Excellent' data-value='4'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
              <li class='star' title='WOW!!!' data-value='5'>
                <i class='fa fa-star fa-fw'></i>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
          <div class='success-box'>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            <!-- <img alt='tick image' width='32' src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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'/> -->
            <div class='text-message'></div>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
          </div>
          
      </section>  
      <div id="feedback" style="margin-bottom: 164px;">
        <textarea name="feedback" id="feedbackContent" placeholder="Please Proveide the feedback" class="feedback"></textarea>

      </div>   
      <div class="submit" id="submit">
        <button class="btn-submit" id="feedSubmit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      
      
      </div>
```